# How to get parent-child data in one table like pivot table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, parent-child, hierarchical-data

Hello great developers!

I have an issue related to child-parent field in MySQL. Here, I create an schema here in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d16b61/1).

I have 2 table.

sys_user table

```
| username | userDisplayName | userTypeCode |
|----------|-----------------|--------------|
|    adhan |           Adhan |         ENTL |
|    aruto |           Aruto |         RWTL |
|    berry |           Berry |         EDTL |
|   chiira |          Chiira |         QCED |
```

sys_usertype table

```
| userTypeCode |       userTypeName | userTypeCodeParent | userTypeLevel |
|--------------|--------------------|--------------------|---------------|
|         EDTL |  Editor Translator |               MSTL |             2 |
|         ENTL | English Translator |               RWTL |             3 |
|         MSTL |         Translator |                    |             1 |
|         QCED |    Quality Checker |                    |             1 |
|         RWTL |     Raw Translator |               MSTL |             2 |
```

So, I have tried this query:

```
SELECT usr.*, 
  usrty_lv1.userTypeName AS userTypeLevel1 ,
  usrty_lv2.userTypeName AS userTypeLevel2, 
  usrty.userTypeName AS userTypeLevel3 
FROM sys_user usr
LEFT JOIN sys_usertype usrty 
  ON usr.userTypeCode = usrty.userTypeCode
LEFT JOIN sys_usertype usrty_lv2 
  ON usrty.userTypeCodeParent = usrty_lv2.userTypeCode
LEFT JOIN sys_usertype usrty_lv1 
  ON usrty_lv2.userTypeCodeParent = usrty_lv1.userTypeCode
```

And the result is:

```
====================================================================================================
|  username  | userDisplayName | userTypeCode | userTypeLevel1 | userTypeLevel2 |  userTypeLevel3  |
====================================================================================================
| chiira     | Chiira          | QCED         | (null)         | (null)         | Quality Checker  |
| adhan      | Adhan           | ENTL         | Translator     | Raw Translator | English Transl.. |
| berry      | Berry           | EDTL         | (null)         | Translator     | Editor Transla.. |
| aruto      | Aruto           | RWTL         | (null)         | Translator     | Raw TransLator   |
====================================================================================================
```

My goal is produce this result:

```
====================================================================================================
|  username  | userDisplayName | userTypeCode | userTypeLevel1 | userTypeLevel2 |  userTypeLevel3  |
====================================================================================================
| chiira     | Chiira          | QCED         | Quality Chec.. | (null)         | (null)           |
| adhan      | Adhan           | ENTL         | Translator     | Raw Translator | English Transl.. |
| berry      | Berry           | EDTL         | Translator     | Editor Trans.. | (null)           |
| aruto      | Aruto           | RWTL         | Translator     | Raw TransLator | (null)           |
====================================================================================================
```

How to achieve that? Am I doing wrong?
I'm prefer not using CTE, because I have many data :(

Thank you so much.

Comment: What has 'many data' got to do with the choice, or otherwise of CTE?

Comment: Ah, I have maximum 3 depth level of usertype table. Thats why I tried using ```LEFT JOIN```.